# nginx always serves welcome page

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to make nginx proxy requests to a Django server, but it keeps showing the nginx welcome page.

Here's `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
worker_processes  4;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile       off;

    tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    server {
        listen 8000 default_server;
        listen [::]:8000 default_server ipv6only=on;
    }
}
```

and here's `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/dotmanca` (the only file in the `site-enabled` directory):

```
server {
    server_name _;

    access_log off;

    location /media/ {
        alias /vagrant/media/;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /vagrant/static/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
    }
}
```

So with no server running on port 8001, I expect a bad gateway error to show up. Instead I see the default "Welcome to nginx!"

Running `sudo nginx -t` gives the following:

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Also, `sudo service nginx restart` appears to do nothing.

My nginx version is 1.4.6, and it's running on Ubuntu Trusty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So removing the `server` section from `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and adding the two `listen` directives to the `server` section in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/dotmanca` appears to work.

Or at least, it allows `sudo nginx -s reload` to fix the issue.